# What is import gv in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I installed `easy_install` under windows, and installed `pygraph` but the commad `import gv` in the example taken from [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/wiki/Example) doesn't work:

What is gv lib? what `import gv` does?

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\graph.py", line 11, in <module>
    import gv
ImportError: No module named gv
```

All the other imports works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could have multiple problem sources:

1. While installing, something went wrong and the module couldn't be installed.
2. You haven't set your [Python Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) correctly.
3. <s>@second example: The module pygraph.readwrite could exists, but it's possible that it hasn't got a submodule called dot.</s>

Of course there are sure other possibile problems, but I think this would be the most likely.

**Edit:** Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/issues/detail?id=15). Looks like it's the same problem as yours.

<s>For the second problem eventually [this discussion](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/issues/detail?id=94) may also help.</s>

Answer (score 4):

Try to install `libgv-python` with your package manager. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libgv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common issue with python-graph, see the discussion at http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/issues/detail?id=15. `gv` is GraphViz and apparently something with the place or the bindings of this library is wrong. You might have to modify `sys.path`, but it might be even more troublesome on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

From python-graph's ["Issue 15: import gv"](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/issues/detail?id=15#c10):

> It appears that graphviz for windows has no python bindings, or they are not 
>   included with the installer, and not available elsewhere.
>
> Furthermore, I can find no mention of libgv-python (the library which gv is from, I 
>   think) *ever* being available on windows.

You can workaround the absent gv.py by using the command line tools directly.

Assuming you're trying the [example code](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/wiki/Example), remove these lines:

```
sys.path.append('..')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/graphviz/python/')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/graphviz/python/')
import gv
```

And remove these lines:

```
gvv = gv.readstring(dot)
gv.layout(gvv,'dot')
gv.render(gvv,'png','europe.png')
```

And add these lines instead, making sure the path to dot.exe is correct, or is otherwise in your PATH:

```
f = open('europe.dot', 'a')
f.write(dot)
f.close()
import os
command = '"C:\\Program Files\\Graphviz 2.28\\bin\\dot.exe" -Tpng europe.dot > europe.png'
print command
os.system(command)
os.system('europe.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Module **gv** corresponding to graphviz-python a python binding of graphviz
See : http://www.graphviz.org/Home.php